# Как реализовать обработку onClick для ячеек большой таблицы?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Допустим есть приложение, которое содержит одну довольно большую таблицу. Приложение должно уметь обрабатывать нажатия на ячейки таблицы(это нужно для возможности редактирования ячеек таблицы). 
Есть ли возможность определять к какой ячейке нажал пользователь не используя event.target(ведь он не работает в IE8) и не прописывая     `onClick="..."` к каждой ячейке(я слышал, что так неэффективно)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно есть возможность определить событие на какой ячейке сработало. Пробуйте так.

```js
$('td').on('click', function(){
   if ($(this).css('background-color') == 'rgb(255, 255, 255)') {
      $(this).css('background-color','tomato');
   } else {
      $(this).css('background-color','rgb(255, 255, 255)');
   }  
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>01</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>21</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```